# Java- Adding unique values to Hashmap

Tags: java

ok,

here is my issue....I have a `List<short>letterList` which has for example: "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"

What Im doing is Im iterating over this list then passing the value into another method which returns a value:

so:

```
string value = null;
for(Short foo : letterList)

{
   value = getSomeValue(foo) //returns a letter A or B or C
}
```

What Im trying to do is get a hashmap to look something like this:

```
key: a, value 1,5,7
key b, value: 2,3,4
key c, value: 6,8,9,10
```

not these values specifically, but you get my point

Im not sure how to do this  I have tried creating a map with a `<set<string>, List<short>`

any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You can use Map<Character, List<Short>>. If you use strings for keys, then just change Character to String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has no built-in MultiMap, but you can either simulate a multimap (`Map<String, List<Short>>`) or try out Guava for example: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Comment: Im using `Multimap<Short, Short> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();`

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap<Character, List<Short>> map`

My understanding was you were looking for a simple way to store a list of values with a character? If so, use that above.

If you want to sort by letter (for easy printing out) use the following:

`TreeMap<Character, List<Short>> map`

You can get and of the values by using `map.get('A')` and using your standard methods to iterate through or get a certain value from the associated list.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<Short>>
```

The key (String) will be unique. The List<> will be able to hold a list of shorts.

If you want to make sure the numbers are unique as well as the keys, then use a Set instead of a list.

Remember to initialize the lists you put in the map (getting a key like "A" for the first time will return null, so check if it's null and if it is then create a List, put your value into it, and put the list into the map).

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your complete use case, I would suggest having a different look at your data structure organization. e.g.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Where the keys are 1,2....10 as in your example and the values are

```
1 -> a
2 -> b
3 -> b
etc.
```

To get your original "list" you can use -

```
Set<Integer>  numbers = map.keySet();
```

Comment: you have it reverse..the letters that come out of the method are the keys

Comment: Yes I am suggesting that he actually reverse his data structure, that will be much faster lookup.